# Как правильно отделять логику отрисовки от бизнес логики в GUI приложениях?

Tags: java, gui, проектирование

Есть проект на Java, где присутствует код отрисовки окон, кнопок и т.п. + есть код, который выполняет какие-либо действия в соответствии с этим интерфейсом. Вопрос: как грамотно совмещать код отрисовки+код выполнения. Где можно про это почитать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шаблон Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) используется для разделения модели и её представления, что необходимо для изменения их отдельно друг от друга. Почитайте про него.